# Counting how many times a loop is performed

Tags: javascript, arrays, do-while

I am assigned a task of creating a dice game. The object of the game is to bet a $ amount and the dice will repeatedly roll until the user runs out of money. I have to count the amount of times the user rolled the dice before the money ran out and store it in an array. I have used a do..while loop to perform the dice roll function, I am confused as to how I can count the number of times the do..while loop was ran and store this in an array. A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated thanks!

```
   <script>
        var rolls = new Array();
        var maxMoney = new Array();
        var rollCountMoney = new Array();
        function rollDice(){
        do {
        var userInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("bet").value); 
        var wallet = userInput; 
        var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var diceTotal = d1 + d2;
            if(diceTotal === 7) {
                document.getElementById("bet").value = wallet += 4;
                alert("your rolled a " +diceTotal +"! You win $4");
        } else {
                document.getElementById("bet").value = wallet -= 1;
                alert("your rolled a " +diceTotal +"! You lose $1");
            }
        } while (wallet > 0) { 
        }

        } 
    </script>
</head>
<body>          
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="page-head"> 
            <h1 align="center">Lucky Sevens</h1>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="container" align="center"> 
        <table style="border: 1px solid black"> 
            <tr>
                <th><h3 align="center">Lucky Sevens</h3></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form>
                        Starting Bet: 
                        <input id="bet" type="text"/>
                    </form>
                </td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <button onclick="rollDice()">Play</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use a counter variable. Initialize it to zero before loop starts. Increment it by one in the loop. Outside of the loop, you'll get number of times the loop is executed.

Comment: Do you want the count of rollDice() function? what I mean to ask is are you trying to count the number of times the user Played roll dice?

Comment: Why do you need `do...while` in this case ?

Comment: @progrAmmar Yes amount of times the user played roll dice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your code and variable name. You can keep result like this...

```js
var rolls = new Array();
var maxMoney = 0;//Max Money
var rollCountMoney = new Array();
var count = 0;

function rollDice() {
  do {
    count++;
    var userInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("bet").value);
    var wallet = userInput;
    var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var diceTotal = d1 + d2;
    rolls.push(diceTotal);//keep the roll
    rollCountMoney.push(wallet);//keep the wallet
    if(wallet > maxMoney){
      maxMoney = wallet;//keep the max money
    }
    if (diceTotal === 7) {
      document.getElementById("bet").value = wallet += 4;
      alert("Round:" + count + ",your rolled a " + diceTotal + "! You win $4");
    } else {
      document.getElementById("bet").value = wallet -= 1;
      alert("Round:" + count + ",your rolled a " + diceTotal + "! You lose $1");
    }
  } while (wallet > 0) {}
  var displayMsg = "You have rolled " + count + " times!";
  displayMsg += "<br>Rolls:" + rolls;
  displayMsg += "<br>maxMoney:" + maxMoney;
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = displayMsg;


}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="page-head">
    <h1 align="center">Lucky Sevens</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" align="center">
  <table style="border: 1px solid black">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h3 align="center">Lucky Sevens</h3>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form>
          Starting Bet:
          <input id="bet" type="text" />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <button onclick="rollDice()">Play</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" id="display"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That helped me out a ton, thank you very much! The one thing I am still struggling with is how to show how many rolls were taken when the user had the most money.

Comment: you can keep it in another variable when `maxMoney` has been recorded and show it after the while loop. If this post helped, don't forget to mark it as answer.